# intellisense javascript in visual studio code has very bad suggestions

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I write this code in VSCode:

```
    export default class User{
    static USER_DIALOG_STATUS = {
        LEARN: 1, 
        AUTHORIZE: 2,   
        WAIT_LEARN: 3,  
    };
    static USER_AUTH_STATUS = {
        GUEST: 1,
        AUTHORIZED: 2,
        PREAUTHORIZED: 3,
    };
    dialog_statuses(p_status){
        switch(p_status)
            case this.USER_DIALOG_STATUS.

---
```

on last dot(`case this.USER_DIALOG_STATUS.`) i retrieve more then ten suggestions from intellisense:

```
            AUTHORIZE
            AUTHORIZED
            GUEST
            PREAUTHORIZED
            USER_AUTH_STATUS
            USER_DIALOG_STATUS
            User
            WAIT_LEARN
            WORDS_LEARN
```

Why? And how get only normal three:

```
        AUTHORIZE
        LEARN
        WAIT_LEARN
```

Comment: Javascript is dynamic and without any form of typing it's suggestions are never going to be great.  It's the exact reason we have Typscript, if you want really good intellisense I would suggest you look into using Typescript.

Comment: Maybe with JS VSCode can't make ideal suggestions, but that... I can take paper, look all code and write all need suggestions. V8 can do it to and show this in debug mode. Why it can't make IDE/Editor?
Maybe has any plugin what do that?

Comment: `this.USER_DIALOG_STATUS`, did you mean `User.USER_DIALOG_STATUS.`  static is not part of the object, it's part of the User class.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `this.USER_DIALOG_STATUS` for static object intellisense suggestion.
Use `User.USER_DIALOG_STATUS.` for class (on this example)

Thanks to Keith!